# Using a lambda in a `constexpr` function in a non-`constexpr` context: clang vs gcc

Tags: c++, lambda, language-lawyer, c++14, constexpr

Consider the following code *([available on gcc.godbolt.org](https://goo.gl/a7ZZ8Z))*:

```
template <typename TF>
constexpr auto fn_x(TF f)
{
    return f();
}

constexpr auto get_x()
{
    return fn_x([]{ return 0; });
}

int main()
{
    auto res = get_x();
}
```

It compiles under **g++ 5.3.x** and newer *(including **g++ 6.x.x**)*.

It does not compile under **clang++ 3.7.x** and newer with the following error:

```
error: constexpr function never produces a constant expression [-Winvalid-constexpr]
constexpr auto get_x()
               ^
note: subexpression not valid in a constant expression
        return fn_x([]{ return 0; });
```

A possible solution to make the code compile with both gcc and clang is using a "layer of indirection" with `decltype`, also getting rid of the `constexpr` in the function where the lambda is defined: [gcc.godbolt.org link](https://goo.gl/ecE1Km).

**Which compiler is correct here according to the standard?**

Comment: Anyway, perhaps more relevant to your question: do any of the compilers you test with claim that `get_x()` can be used in a constant expression? If not, is your question "am I allowed to add `constexpr` to functions that can't ever be used in constant expressions?"

Comment: @hvd: Regarding the semicolons, I do always compile real code with `-Wpedantic`, which informs me of the mistake. I'm used to writing lambda-heavy code (`auto l = []{ ... };`) so sometimes my brain automatically adds a semicolon at the end of a function.

Comment: @hvd It's valid C++11 - the `;` is an *empty-declaration*. See [CWG 569](http://wg21.link/cwg569).

Comment: @T.C. I stand corrected! That looks like a bug in GCC then for continuing to reject it in a meant-to-be-conforming mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both of the compilers are in agreement that `get_x()` can't be used in a constant expression. You can tell by changing `auto res = get_x();` to `constexpr auto res = get_x();`, where GCC will reject it equally.

As for detecting it at function definition time like clang does rather than at function use like gcc does, both are allowed: (emphasis mine)

> **7.1.5 The constexpr specifier [dcl.constexpr]**
>
> 5 For a non-template, non-defaulted `constexpr` function or a non-template, non-defaulted, non-inheriting `constexpr` constructor, if no argument values exist such that an invocation of the function or constructor could be an evaluated subexpression of a core constant expression (5.19), the program is ***ill-formed; no diagnostic required***. [...]

It is impossible in the general case to reliably detect whether a function invocation exists that allows the result to be used in a constant expression, which is why the diagnostic is optional.

Comment: As an aside, the lack of `constexpr` support from lambdas is a bit of a missing feature in C++.  [Here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4487.pdf) is such a proposal.